# Multiple text data-bind using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi i am trying to do a double data-bind on a option text. Now i want to include 2 things within the select drop-down.

I have tried this and it only brings back the last data-bind of the description.
is there a way to do 1 data-bind and include both values using knockout?

```
<option value="" data-bind="text: Name, text: Description"></option>
```

Comment: try this that should do it  http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/40/ . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<option value="" data-bind="text: Name() + ' ' + Description()"></option>
```

Or better create a computed observable:

```
this.ComputedName = ko.computed(function (){ 
    return this.Name() + ' ' + this.Description();
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<option value="" data-bind="text: ComputedName"></option>
```

You might also consider [options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) instead.